# Zend Framework and nested sets

Tags: php, nested-sets, zend-framework

we`re currently developing our own Feedmanager for ShopProducts based on Zend Framework.
In this feedmanager you can manage several feeds, to be created and sent to different locations.
Each feed has n-fields which are in the current version only in one level.
Now we want to change it to a multilevel version, we we have parentfields and childfields.

We dont want to reinvent the wheel, so we would like to use a developed class or helper.

I found the class of F. Pietka.
https://github.com/fpietka/Zend-Nested-Set
I tried to use this helper in our system, but had no success.

I wrote the following line, to use the class:

```
$oNested = new NestedSet_Model();
```

I got the following error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method NestedSet_Model::getDbTable() in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\feedmanager_alpha\application\classes\NestedSet.class.php
>   on line 75

In the readme of Peitka`s NestedSet helper it says that the ZendLibrary needs to be in the include path.

I think I did this with the following lines:

```
define("ROOTPATH", realpath("../"));
define("LIBPATH", ROOTPATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'library' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(
    implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,
        array(
            realpath(LIBPATH)
        )
    )
);
```

Did I set the include path correctly? 
What could be the problem in my case?
Is a nested-set the best way to create the parent-child-model?

Comment: This doesn't look like there is something wrong with the include path. The error states that the class `NestedSet_Model` does not have the function/method called `getDbTable()`. It can find the class fine, it's the method call that errors. Are you sure this class has that method?

Comment: Hey jakenoble, at first: thanks for your comment. The class NestedSet_Model doesnt have this method. I thought this Class is complete? How could nobody else have recongnized this missing function?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise you not to use this class, because it's clearly a WIP. However, if you want to circumvent this error, you can just delete the __construct() method and call the setDb() and setTableName() by hand.

Example:

```
$model = new NestedSet_Model();
$model->setDb(Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter());
$model->setTableName('table_name');
```

Comment: Can you recommend other (better) class for handling nested sets in zend framework?

Answer (score 0):

```
class NestedSet extends Zend_Db_Table
{
    protected $_name = 't_nested_set_mkb_10';

    public function set(){
        $model = new NestedSet_Model();
        $model->setDb(Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter());
        $model->setTableName('t_nested_set_mkb_10');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was long overdue, but I updated https://github.com/fpietka/Zend-Nested-Set (even with unit tests).

Feel free to create issues!